# Getting “Code: Bad RIP Value” kernel panic when trying to boot up after reboot

Tags: networking, kernel, panic

**Description of problem:**

> I have installed Debian 10 Buster. EA01A NEC M2M LTE Dongle is attached to Device and configured for internet access.
> I have scheduled a reboot everyday at 1 AM. and I have noticed some times after reboot the system does not boot up properly. And shows “Code: Bad RIP value”.
> This issue does not always occur and is not able to be reproduced yet.

**Machine details:**

```
Machine details:
root@DEB:/home# lscpu 
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
Address sizes:       39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               142
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8109U CPU @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:            10
CPU MHz:             2000.001
CPU max MHz:         3600.0000
CPU min MHz:         400.0000
BogoMIPS:            6000.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3

root@DEB:/home# uname -a
Linux DEB 4.19.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.132-1 (2020-07-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

> Following are the syslogs at the time of reboot:

**Logs:**

```
2020-11-13T01:07:57.591035+09:00 <daemon.info> smartd[520]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.SPCC_M_2_SSD-P2000559000000025478.ata.state
2020-11-13T01:07:57.591139+09:00 <daemon.info> smartd[520]: Monitoring 1 ATA/SATA, 0 SCSI/SAS and 0 NVMe devices
2020-11-13T01:07:57.591546+09:00 <daemon.info> systemd[1]: Started LSB: Color ANSI System Logo.
2020-11-13T01:07:57.593915+09:00 <daemon.info> smartd[520]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.SPCC_M_2_SSD-P2000559000000025478.ata.state
2020-11-13T01:07:57.598691+09:00 <daemon.info> accounts-daemon[502]: started daemon version 0.6.45
2020-11-13T01:07:57.598824+09:00 <daemon.info> systemd[1]: Started Accounts Service.
2020-11-13T01:07:57.601006+09:00 <daemon.info> dphys-swapfile[518]: computing size, want /var/swap=15708MByte, restricting to 50% of remaining disk size: 6701MBytes, restricting to config limit: 4096MBytes, checking existing: keeping it
2020-11-13T01:07:57.646702+09:00 <daemon.info> loadcpufreq[504]: Loading cpufreq kernel modules...done (acpi-cpufreq).
2020-11-13T01:07:57.647011+09:00 <daemon.info> systemd[1]: Started LSB: Load kernel modules needed to enable cpufreq scaling.
2020-11-13T01:07:57.647738+09:00 <daemon.info> systemd[1]: Starting LSB: set CPUFreq kernel parameters...
2020-11-13T01:07:57.654960+09:00 <daemon.info> cpufrequtils[645]: CPUFreq Utilities: Setting ondemand CPUFreq governor...disabled, governor not available...done.
2020-11-13T01:07:57.655231+09:00 <daemon.info> systemd[1]: Started LSB: set CPUFreq kernel parameters.
2020-11-13T01:07:57.673396+09:00 <daemon.info> systemd[1]: Started dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file.
2020-11-13T01:07:57.674051+09:00 <kern.info> kernel: [  189.360869] Adding 4194300k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-2 extents:8 across:6258688k SSFS
2020-11-13T01:07:57.872792+09:00 <daemon.info> systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
2020-11-13T01:07:58.538721+09:00 <daemon.info> systemd[1]: Started Save/Restore Sound Card State.
2020-11-13T01:07:58.539084+09:00 <daemon.info> systemd[1]: Reached target Sound Card.
2020-11-13T01:08:14.530986+09:00 <daemon.notice> nscd: 517 checking for monitored file `/etc/resolv.conf': No such file or directory
2020-11-13T01:08:27.606987+09:00 <daemon.warning> dbus-daemon[513]: [system] Connection has not authenticated soon enough, closing it (auth_timeout=30000ms, elapsed: 30029ms)
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154249+09:00 <kern.err> kernel: [  242.838955] INFO: task systemd-udevd:291 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154283+09:00 <kern.err> kernel: [  242.838967]       Tainted: G     U            4.19.0-12-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.152-1
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154287+09:00 <kern.err> kernel: [  242.838970] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154291+09:00 <kern.info> kernel: [  242.838975] systemd-udevd   D    0   291    277 0x00000324
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154295+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.838979] Call Trace:
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154321+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.838989]  __schedule+0x29f/0x840
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154326+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.838995]  schedule+0x28/0x80
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154330+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.838999]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0xa/0x10
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154333+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839001]  __mutex_lock.isra.8+0x2b5/0x4a0
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154335+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839006]  ? addrconf_notify+0x31c/0xae0
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154338+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839016]  nf_tables_netdev_event+0x9b/0x1a0 [nf_tables]
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154341+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839023]  notifier_call_chain+0x47/0x70
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154344+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839028]  dev_change_name+0x1fa/0x330
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154347+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839033]  do_setlink+0x729/0xef0
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154350+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839040]  ? blk_mq_dispatch_rq_list+0x392/0x590
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154353+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839044]  ? elv_rb_del+0x1f/0x30
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154356+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839047]  ? deadline_remove_request+0x55/0xc0
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154359+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839050]  ? blk_mq_do_dispatch_sched+0x91/0x120
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154362+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839054]  ? __d_alloc+0x24/0x240
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154364+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839058]  rtnl_setlink+0xd9/0x130
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154368+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839065]  rtnetlink_rcv_msg+0x2b1/0x360
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154370+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839069]  ? _cond_resched+0x15/0x30
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154373+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839072]  ? rtnl_calcit.isra.33+0x100/0x100
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154374+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839076]  netlink_rcv_skb+0x4c/0x120
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154377+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839081]  netlink_unicast+0x181/0x210
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154380+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839084]  netlink_sendmsg+0x204/0x3d0
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154382+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839088]  sock_sendmsg+0x36/0x40
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154384+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839090]  __sys_sendto+0xee/0x160
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154387+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839096]  ? syscall_trace_enter+0x192/0x2b0
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154390+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839099]  __x64_sys_sendto+0x24/0x30
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154392+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839102]  do_syscall_64+0x53/0x110
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154395+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839105]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154398+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839108] RIP: 0033:0x7fdf27a749b7
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154401+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839115] Code: Bad RIP value.
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154403+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839117] RSP: 002b:00007ffc41f57038 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002c
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154406+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839119] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000557b32c847a0 RCX: 00007fdf27a749b7
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154408+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839120] RDX: 0000000000000034 RSI: 0000557b32c84be0 RDI: 000000000000000f
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154411+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839121] RBP: 0000000000000003 R08: 00007ffc41f570f0 R09: 0000000000000010
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154413+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839123] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000557b32c77898
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154416+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839124] R13: 0000557b32c84ca0 R14: 0000557b32c69150 R15: 0000557b32c5fe70
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154419+09:00 <kern.err> kernel: [  242.839148] INFO: task systemd-udevd:320 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154423+09:00 <kern.err> kernel: [  242.839154]       Tainted: G     U            4.19.0-12-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.152-1
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154426+09:00 <kern.err> kernel: [  242.839157] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154428+09:00 <kern.info> kernel: [  242.839161] systemd-udevd   D    0   320    277 0x80000324
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154432+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839163] Call Trace:
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154436+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839169]  __schedule+0x29f/0x840
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154439+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839173]  schedule+0x28/0x80
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154443+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839177]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0xa/0x10
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154448+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839179]  __mutex_lock.isra.8+0x2b5/0x4a0
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154475+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839184]  register_netdevice_notifier+0x37/0x230
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154481+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839189]  ? kobject_put+0x23/0x1b0
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154486+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839192]  ? 0xffffffffc0c39000
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154490+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839231]  cfg80211_init+0x37/0xcb [cfg80211]
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154494+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839237]  do_one_initcall+0x46/0x1c3
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154497+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839241]  ? free_unref_page_commit+0x91/0x100
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154499+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839245]  ? _cond_resched+0x15/0x30
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154502+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839249]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x15e/0x1e0
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154505+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839254]  do_init_module+0x5a/0x210
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154510+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839258]  load_module+0x2167/0x23d0
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154513+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839264]  ? __do_sys_finit_module+0xad/0x110
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154517+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839266]  __do_sys_finit_module+0xad/0x110
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154520+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839271]  do_syscall_64+0x53/0x110
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154523+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839274]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154526+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839276] RIP: 0033:0x7fdf27a6df59
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154545+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839281] Code: Bad RIP value.
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154548+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839282] RSP: 002b:00007ffc41f56b68 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154550+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839284] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000557b32c77180 RCX: 00007fdf27a6df59
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154553+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839285] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007fdf27972cad RDI: 000000000000000f
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154556+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839286] RBP: 00007fdf27972cad R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154558+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839287] R10: 000000000000000f R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154561+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839289] R13: 0000557b32c663d0 R14: 0000000000020000 R15: 0000557b32c77180
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154565+09:00 <kern.err> kernel: [  242.839294] INFO: task modprobe:422 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154567+09:00 <kern.err> kernel: [  242.839299]       Tainted: G     U            4.19.0-12-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.152-1
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154570+09:00 <kern.err> kernel: [  242.839303] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154572+09:00 <kern.info> kernel: [  242.839307] modprobe        D    0   422    406 0x80000000
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154575+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839309] Call Trace:
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154578+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839314]  __schedule+0x29f/0x840
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154580+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839318]  schedule+0x28/0x80
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154582+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839320]  rwsem_down_write_failed+0x17c/0x3a0
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154585+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839324]  ? __wake_up_common_lock+0x89/0xc0
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154587+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839328]  ? 0xffffffffc05cb000
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154589+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839331]  call_rwsem_down_write_failed+0x13/0x20
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154592+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839334]  down_write+0x29/0x40
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154594+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839338]  register_pernet_subsys+0x15/0x40
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154597+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839343]  nf_log_ipv6_init+0x12/0x1000 [nf_log_ipv6]
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154600+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839347]  do_one_initcall+0x46/0x1c3
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154602+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839350]  ? free_unref_page_commit+0x91/0x100
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154604+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839353]  ? _cond_resched+0x15/0x30
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154607+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839357]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x15e/0x1e0
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154609+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839360]  do_init_module+0x5a/0x210
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154628+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839363]  load_module+0x2167/0x23d0
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154632+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839369]  ? __do_sys_finit_module+0xad/0x110
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154634+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839371]  __do_sys_finit_module+0xad/0x110
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154638+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839376]  do_syscall_64+0x53/0x110
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154640+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839379]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154643+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839380] RIP: 0033:0x7f2f86ff6f59
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154645+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839384] Code: Bad RIP value.
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154648+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839386] RSP: 002b:00007ffd08bdd2d8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154650+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839387] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000564e805fefd0 RCX: 00007f2f86ff6f59
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154652+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839389] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000564e7f08d3f0 RDI: 0000000000000000
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154655+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839390] RBP: 0000564e7f08d3f0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154657+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839391] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
2020-11-13T01:08:51.154661+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  242.839392] R13: 0000564e805feed0 R14: 0000000000040000 R15: 0000564e805fefd0
2020-11-13T01:09:27.747860+09:00 <daemon.warning> systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
2020-11-13T01:10:01.537439+09:00 <cron.info> CRON[653]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf >/dev/null 2>&1)
2020-11-13T01:10:20.249057+09:00 <daemon.notice> nscd: 517 checking for monitored file `/etc/resolv.conf': No such file or directory
2020-11-13T01:10:35.249374+09:00 <daemon.notice> nscd: 517 checking for monitored file `/etc/resolv.conf': No such file or directory
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986271+09:00 <kern.err> kernel: [  363.670948] INFO: task systemd-udevd:291 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986302+09:00 <kern.err> kernel: [  363.670959]       Tainted: G     U            4.19.0-12-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.152-1
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986304+09:00 <kern.err> kernel: [  363.670963] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986306+09:00 <kern.info> kernel: [  363.670967] systemd-udevd   D    0   291    277 0x00000324
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986308+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.670970] Call Trace:
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986309+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.670980]  __schedule+0x29f/0x840
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986312+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.670985]  schedule+0x28/0x80
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986314+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.670989]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0xa/0x10
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986339+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.670991]  __mutex_lock.isra.8+0x2b5/0x4a0
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986342+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.670995]  ? addrconf_notify+0x31c/0xae0
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986344+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671006]  nf_tables_netdev_event+0x9b/0x1a0 [nf_tables]
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986346+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671012]  notifier_call_chain+0x47/0x70
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986348+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671017]  dev_change_name+0x1fa/0x330
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986350+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671022]  do_setlink+0x729/0xef0
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986351+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671028]  ? blk_mq_dispatch_rq_list+0x392/0x590
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986353+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671033]  ? elv_rb_del+0x1f/0x30
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986355+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671035]  ? deadline_remove_request+0x55/0xc0
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986356+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671038]  ? blk_mq_do_dispatch_sched+0x91/0x120
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986358+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671042]  ? __d_alloc+0x24/0x240
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986360+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671046]  rtnl_setlink+0xd9/0x130
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986362+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671054]  rtnetlink_rcv_msg+0x2b1/0x360
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986364+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671058]  ? _cond_resched+0x15/0x30
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986365+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671061]  ? rtnl_calcit.isra.33+0x100/0x100
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986367+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671065]  netlink_rcv_skb+0x4c/0x120
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986368+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671069]  netlink_unicast+0x181/0x210
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986370+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671073]  netlink_sendmsg+0x204/0x3d0
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986371+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671076]  sock_sendmsg+0x36/0x40
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986373+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671079]  __sys_sendto+0xee/0x160
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986374+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671084]  ? syscall_trace_enter+0x192/0x2b0
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986376+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671087]  __x64_sys_sendto+0x24/0x30
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986378+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671090]  do_syscall_64+0x53/0x110
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986379+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671093]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986381+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671096] RIP: 0033:0x7fdf27a749b7
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986383+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671103] Code: Bad RIP value.
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986384+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671105] RSP: 002b:00007ffc41f57038 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002c
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986386+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671108] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000557b32c847a0 RCX: 00007fdf27a749b7
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986387+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671109] RDX: 0000000000000034 RSI: 0000557b32c84be0 RDI: 000000000000000f
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986389+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671110] RBP: 0000000000000003 R08: 00007ffc41f570f0 R09: 0000000000000010
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986390+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671111] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000557b32c77898
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986391+09:00 <kern.warning> kernel: [  363.671112] R13: 0000557b32c84ca0 R14: 0000557b32c69150 R15: 0000557b32c5fe70
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986393+09:00 <kern.err> kernel: [  363.671120] INFO: task systemd-udevd:320 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986394+09:00 <kern.err> kernel: [  363.671125]       Tainted: G     U            4.19.0-12-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.152-1
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986396+09:00 <kern.err> kernel: [  363.671129] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
2020-11-13T01:10:51.986398+09:00 <kern.info> kernel: [  363.671132] systemd-udevd   D    0   320    277 0x80000324
```

I am wondering if this is happens because of USB dongle, from above logs it seems something systemd-udevd netlink and rtnetlink send and receive message in “Call Trace”
Thank you so much in advance for your help.